# Which HTTP code should the server return for my particular case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, web, error-handling

The scenario that I have:

`User 1` wants to edit some data on the server, and he sends a request to lock the data for editing.

Assume, that the data that `User 1` wants to edit and trying to lock already locked by `User 2` and `User 2` is doing editing now.

How should I notify `User 1` that the server has to reject his request and doesn't allow any editing for `User 1` for now?

I believe, that the server should return 4xx client error, but I am not sure with one exactly.
Possible it should be *403 Forbidden*?

Answer (score 1):

I would use http code 409. Check it here for more details https://httpstatuses.com/409

Answer (score 0):

I will use a "409 Conflict". It indicates that the state of your server has changed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409

Answer (score 0):

I think it must return "423 Locked": The resource that is being accessed is locked.